# Robot Framework - importing of external python libraries are not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

I have a robot framework project with below folder & file structure.

[image]

The `logger.py` file is as below.

```
def log_into_console():
    print("log_into_console() method executed")
```

The `message_printer.py` file is as below.

```
# This line cause the problem. it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib.Common'"
from Lib.Common.logger import log_into_console

def print_message():
    print("print_message() method executed")
    log_into_console()
```

I want to call above `print_message()` function inside my robot test case as below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    ../Lib/Util/message_printer.py

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Robot Test Case
    print message
```

**My problem is** When I execute the test, it complains that it couldn't find the **Lib.Common** module. I'm getting below error when I execute the test.

```
D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\RobotFiles>robot Test.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\RobotFiles\Test.robot' on line 3: Importing test library 'D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\Lib\Util\message_printer.p
y' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib.Common'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\Lib\Util\message_printer.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Lib.Common.logger
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\robot.exe
  c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.zip
  c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs
  c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
  c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37
  c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
My Test Robot Test Case                                               | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'print message' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\RobotFiles\output.xml
Log:     D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\RobotFiles\log.html
Report:  D:\WorkSpace\POC\Robot\ExternalLibTest\RobotFiles\report.html
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

#1: To solve **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib.Common'"** error, try below one

```
from logger import log_into_console

def print_message():
    print("print_message() method executed")
    log_into_console()
```

since your function log_into_console present in the same directory you can directly use **logger** instead of **Lib.Common.logger**. To get more details refer below link
[https://intellipaat.com/community/9924/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20call,b](https://intellipaat.com/community/9924/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20call,b))

#2: You can do below changes in robot file to solve **No keyword with name 'print message' found** error

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Lib

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Robot Test Case
    Lib.message_printer
```

Let me know if you face any error when you try this!

Comment: Thanks for the response on this. But both your solutions are not working.

**#1.** "logger.py" cannot be accessed directly within "message_printer.py" because both python files are located in two different folders.

**#2.** `Library Lib` is pointing to different inbuilt python library. I tried `Library  ../Lib` but I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: #1. Yes, since both py file are located in different , need to use ```from logger import log_into_console```

Comment: #2 Library part is correct, did you changed to log instead of print code. If you use print in testcase it will consider it as keyword and will looking for it. Add screen shot after trying my complete code to debug again